# Get value of scope variable in controller AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have to fetch value of scope variable defined in directives. I have to get value of that scope variable in controller using AngularJS. How can i fetch value of scope variable?

### Directive

```
app.directive('checkToggle', function() {
    return { 
        scope: true,
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).on('click', function() {
                $(element).find('i').toggleClass('icon-check icon-check-empty');
                if ($(element).find('i').hasClass('icon-check')) {
                    $scope.isChecked = 'true';
                } else {
                    $scope.isChecked = 'false';
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I have to get $scope.isChecked value in controller.

Comment: could you share fiddle or plunker demo of what u have tried ?

Comment: Your question is too broad.. Can you provide more details of what you are trying to do?  
Also, you should not be setting scope variables in the directive and accessing them in controller..

Comment: Sure wait.. I put some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your use-case correctly you would like to toggle an icon on click. If so you don't need to write any directive for this. And provided that you would like to write a directive your shouldn't go about it as you've started. Your code is very imperative, jQuery-like while AngularJS power is in driving declarative UI based on model changes.

Anyway, toggling an icon can be easily done with standard AngularJS directives:

```
<i ng-class="{'icon-star' : isChecked, 'icon-star-empty': !isChecked}" ng-click="isChecked = !isChecked"></i>
```

Here is a working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/nXXQA41w00Cpeo6tTibg?p=preview

Comment: Thank u pkozlowski.opensource